# search and replace value in PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, replace

I was looking for some standard PHP function to replace some value of an array with other, but surprisingly I haven't found any, so I have to write my own:

```
function array_replace_value(&$ar, $value, $replacement)
{
    if (($key = array_search($ar, $value)) !== FALSE) {
        $ar[$key] = $replacement;
    }
}
```

But I still wonder - **for such an easy thing there must already be some function for it**! Or maybe much easier solution than this one invented by me?

Note that this function will only do one replacement. I'm looking for existing solutions that similarly replace a single occurrence, as well as those that replace all occurrences.

Comment: Note that arrays are passed by value. You'll either need to return the new array from the function (matching the behavior of the rest of the `array_*` functions) or make `array_replace_value` take `$ar` by reference.

Comment: [str_replace](http://www.php.net/str_replace)() takes arrays, but you can't limit it to one replacement.

Comment: Thanks @outis, I realized this myself during debugging in the meantime :)

Comment: @Tomas: when you note the function only performs one replacement, are you pointing out a flaw or noting the desired behavior?

Comment: @outis, actually, both :) Now it is desired but for another uses it might become a flaw :)

Comment: @chris: `str_replace` also performs substring replacement, where Tomas' function only replaces exact matches.

Comment: @Tomas: depending on what you're using the string arrays for, it may make more sense (and be more efficient) to use the strings as indices rather than values. For example, sets of strings are better implemented that way.

Comment: @outis, no, because the order of the strings is important, it is natural to have it as values, like `array('apple', 'coconut', 'banana')`.

Comment: @Tomas: array items preserve insertion order, if that's what you're talking about. [`uksort`](http://php.net/uksort) will turn other orderings to an insertion ordering; arbitrary orderings can be supported by using an array of string=>index (which could be the same as the array to be sorted), the flip of the array you currently have, though updating the order array becomes expensive.

Comment: function array_replace_value(array $subject, $search, $replace)
{
    if (($key = array_search($subject, $search)) !== false) {
        $subject[$key] = $replace;
    }
    return $subject;
}

Not a shorter function or anything like this but the updated function that will match the other php array_* functions and the parameter naming also the str_replace for example. But you function was very handy for me and I don't think that there is any shorter way.

Comment: @Gummibeer perhaps you shall form an answer, the code in comment doesn't look nice :-)

Comment: @TMS I know, but it's no real answer cause it's nearly the same code as in the question. But I can if you want. ;)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

While there isn't one function equivalent to the sample code, you can use [`array_keys`](http://php.net/array_keys) (with the optional search value parameter), [`array_fill`](http://php.net/array_fill) and [`array_replace`](http://php.net/array_replace) to achieve the same thing:

**EDIT by Tomas**: the code was not working, corrected it:

```
$ar = array_replace($ar,
    array_fill_keys(
        array_keys($ar, $value),
        $replacement
    )
);
```

Comment: Doesn't `array_replace()` assume you already know the keys? The OP is looking to search and replace by value.

Comment: `array_replace` replaces by key, not value.

Comment: @RaghavBhushan: if you have the key, you don't need `array_replace`.

Comment: @RaghavBhushan: (about your original write-up) [`<br/>`](http://brainstormsandraves.com/articles/semantics/structure/#br) isn't [semantic](http://webstyleguide.com/wsg3/5-site-structure/2-semantic-markup.html). Moreover, you don't need it on SO.

Comment: @RaghavBhushan: Tomas' function already uses `array_search` to find a single item to replace, and the first part of this answer already covers `array_replace`.

Answer (score 42):

Instead of a function that only replaces occurrences of one value in an array, there's the more general `array_map`:

```
array_map(function ($v) use ($value, $replacement) {
    return $v == $value ? $replacement : $v;
}, $arr);
```

To replace multiple occurrences of multiple values using array of value => replacement:

```
array_map(function ($v) use ($replacement) {
    return isset($replacement[$v]) ? $replacement[$v] : $v;
}, $arr);
```

To replace a single occurrence of one value, you'd use `array_search` as you do. Because the implementation is so short, there isn't much reason for the PHP developers to create a standard function to perform the task. Not to say that it doesn't make sense for you to create such a function, if you find yourself needing it often.

Comment: +1. thanks outis for nice answer, I didn't know this syntax, however using map and custom code is a strong tool for this - might be inefficient? I prefer "hardcoded" solution like the Raghav's.

Comment: @Tomas: is the syntax you're referring to [anonymous functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) and closures? Excepting the additional of the "use" specifier, that's more semantics than syntax. As for efficiency, if there is an impact, it's negligible (unless you're performing replacements on perhaps thousands of arrays with each request). One factor affecting performance is that each call to an `array_*` function will create an additional array as its result: one here, three in Raghav's. As always, profiling is the best way of determining performance.

Comment: ... Note that Raghav's doesn't have anything hardcoded that this doesn't, as they all have the same values paramaterized (the array, the value to replace and the replacement value). Hardcoding anything rarely gives a noticeable performance benefit, as the cost of variable lookup is small.

Comment: thanks outis for your answers... however finally I was lucky to use Raghav's solution for one reason: the server of our hosting provider is still running PHP 5.2, so I had to remove all anonymous functions from my code... (I developed on PHP 5.3, so it was a little "betrayal"...)

Comment: @Tomas: I feel your pain. Support for closures is what made PHP bearable.

Answer (score 15):

If performance is an issue, one may consider not to create multiple functions within `array_map()`. Note that `isset()` is extremely fast, and this solutions does not call any other functions at all.

```
$replacements = array(
    'search1' => 'replace1',
    'search2' => 'replace2',
    'search3' => 'replace3'
);
foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
    if (isset($replacements[$value])) {
        $a[$key] = $replacements[$value];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this function.

```
public function recursive_array_replace ($find, $replace, $array) {
    if (!is_array($array)) {
        return str_replace($find, $replace, $array);
    }

    $newArray = [];
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $newArray[$key] = recursive_array_replace($find, $replace, $value);
    }
    return $newArray;
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: This unexplained recursive code makes partial matches/replacements, not necessarily whole value replacements.

Answer (score 6):

`$ar[array_search('green', $ar)] = 'value';`

Comment: Can you add some explanation to your code? What if `array_search` returns false?

Comment: I do not recommend that researchers use this unstable and unexplained snippet.

Answer (score 4):

Depending whether it's the value, the key or both you want to find and replace on you could do something like this:

```
$array = json_decode( str_replace( $replace, $with, json_encode( $array ) ), true );
```

I'm not saying this is the most efficient or elegant, but nice and simple.

Comment: This makes partial matches/replacements, not necessarily whole value replacements.

Answer (score 4):

What about `array_walk()` with callback?

```
$array = ['*pasta', 'cola', 'pizza'];
$search = '*';
$replace = '\*';
array_walk($array,
    function (&$v) use ($search, $replace){
        $v = str_replace($search, $replace, $v);    
    }                                                                     
);  
print_r($array);
```

Comment: This makes partial matches/replacements, not necessarily whole value replacements.

Answer (score 1):

Based on `Deept Raghav`'s answer, I created the follow solution that does regular expression search.

```php
$arr = [
    'Array Element 1',
    'Array Element 2',
    'Replace Me',
    'Array Element 4',
];

$arr = array_replace(
    $arr,
    array_fill_keys(
        array_keys(
            preg_grep('/^Replace/', $arr)
        ),
        'Array Element 3'
    )
);

echo '<pre>', var_export($arr), '</pre>';
```

PhpFiddle: http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/un7u-j1pt

Comment: This makes partial matches/replacements, not necessarily whole value replacements.

Answer (score 1):

PHP 8, a strict version to replace one string value with another:

```php
array_map(fn (string $value): string => $value === $find ? $replace : $value, $array);
```

An example - replace value `foo` with `bar`:

```php
array_map(fn (string $value): string => $value === 'foo' ? 'bar' : $value, $array);
```

Comment: i like your answer but still setting $find and $replace remains challenge. pass a static string is still challange

Answer (score 0):

You can make full string matches without specifying the keys of qualifying values, by calling `preg_replace()` with a pattern containing start and end of string anchors (`^`, `$`).  If your search term may contain characters which have a special meaning to the regex engine, then be sure to escape them with `preg_quote()` to avoid breakage. While regex is not entirely called for, regex offers some very convenient ways to tweak the search term handling. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/uutUI))

```
function array_replace_value(&$ar, $value, $replacement)
{
    $ar = preg_replace(
              '/^' . preg_quote($value, '/') . '$/',
              $replacement,
              $ar
          );
}
```

---

I might be more inclined to use `array_map()` with arrow function syntax so that global variables can be accessed within the custom function scope. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/qOi1t))

```
$needle = 'foo';
$newValue = 'bar';

var_export(
    array_map(fn($v) => $v === $needle ? $newValue : $v, $array)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ar = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
$find = array(2,3);
$replace = array(13);

function update_bundle_package($ar,$find,$replace){
foreach ($find as $x => $y) {
    ///TO REMOVE PACKAGE
    if (($key = array_search($y, $ar)) !== false) {
        unset($ar[$key]);
    }
    ///TO REMOVE PACKAGE
}
$ar = array_merge($ar, $replace); 
}
```

Comment: The asker said: "_I'm looking for existing solutions that similarly replace a single occurrence, as well as those that replace all occurrences._"  `array_search()` will only ever find the first occurrence.

Answer (score -1):

```
 <b>$green_key = array_search('green', $input); // returns the first key whose value is 'green'
```

$input[$green_key] = 'apple'; // replace 'green' with 'apple'

Comment: This is basically what Tomas has, but this doesn't handle the case where a value isn't present in the array.

Comment: The question says: "_I'm looking for existing solutions that similarly replace a single occurrence, as well as those that replace all occurrences._" but this approach will only find the first occurrence.