# In a string if i found any word in any array then it should get replaced with any other word of the same array

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have N array

```
$array[1] = array("a","b","c");
$array[2] = array("p","q","r");
```

In a string if i found any word in any array then it should get replaced with any other word of the same array

Example

```
$text="a d r";
```

then replace `"a"` with any other value of `$array[1]` and `"r"` with any other value of `$array[2]`

How can i do it in PHP ?

Comment: With what value  you want to replace???How you are trying to do ??

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8668826/search-and-replace-value-in-php-array

Comment: "How can i do it in PHP ?" yup

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, but people are willing to help you if you at least try to solve the problem at your own. Please see also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Finally i got the answer, thansk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $total=count($a);
 for($i=0;$i<$total;$i=$i+1)
 {
      $subtotal=count($a[$i]);
      for($j=0;$j<$subtotal;$j=$j+1)
      {
           if(strpos($text,$a[$i][$j]) !== false)
           {
                for($k=0;$k<$subtotal;$k=$k+1)
                {
                     if($a[$i][$j]!=$a[$i][$k])
                     {
                          $text=str_replace($a[$i][$j],"<font color='red'>".$a[$i][$k]."</font>",$text);
                          break;
                     }
                }
                break;
           }
      }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use something like this

```
$array[1] = array("a","b","c"); 
$array[2] = array("p","q","r");

$text="adr";
$finaloutput = '';
foreach(str_split($text) as $val){
    if(in_array($val,$array[1])){
        $k = array_rand($array[1]);
        $v = $array[1][$k];
    }
    elseif(in_array($val,$array[2])){
        $k = array_rand($array[1]);
        $v = $array[1][$k];
    }
    else{
        $v = $val;
    }
    $finaloutput .= $v;
}
echo $finaloutput;
```