# str_replace doesn't work as expected - multi byte character set?

Tags: php, arrays, str-replace

I have a problem with spaces within array `$a2`. I would like to replace `" "` with `""`.

I tried

```
$a2 = str_replace(" ", "", $a2);
```

and even :

```
function str_replace_json($search, $replace, $subject) {
    return json_decode(str_replace($search, $replace, json_encode($subject)), true);
}
$a2 = str_replace_json(" ", "", $a2);
```

But it trims spaces only before and after number (not inside).

My array:

```
$a2 =  array( $rowData[3][1], 
              $rowData[3][2], 
              $rowData[3][3], 
              $rowData[3][4], 
              $rowData[3][5], 
              $rowData[3][6], 
              $rowData[3][7]
            );
```

var_dump of my array:

```
array(7) {  [0]=> string(54) " 155 808.00 " 
            [1]=> string(54) " 131 256.00 " 
            [2]=> string(54) " 106 008.00 " 
            [3]=> string(53) " 60 600.00 " 
            [4]=> string(53) " 41 520.00 " 
            [5]=> string(52) " 5 880.00 " 
            [6]=> string(52) " 6 744.00 " 
        }
```

What might be a reason for that?

**EDIT** 
When I declere my array this way:

```
$a2 = array(
  " 155 808.00 ",
  " 131 256.00 ", 
  " 106 008.00 ", 
  " 60 600.00 ", 
  " 41 520.00 ", 
  " 5 880.00 ", 
  " 6 744.00 " 
);
```

I can easily trim all the spaces (including those inside numbers).

This is how i create `$rowData`

```
include_once ("includes/php/simple_html_dom.php");
$html = file_get_html('https://gaz.tge.pl/pl/rdn/gas/index/index/');
$table = $html->find("table[@class=t-02]",0);
$rowData = array();
foreach($table->find('tr') as $row) {
    $data = array();
    foreach($row->find('td') as $cell) {
           $data[] = $cell->plaintext;
    }
    $rowData[] = $data;
}
array_unshift($rowData[0], "RDNpg");
```

`var_dump` of `$rowData`:

```
array(7) { [0]=> array(8) { [0]=> string(5) "RDNpg" [1]=> string(68) " Pn. 13/02 " [2]=> string(68) " Wt. 14/02 " [3]=> string(69) " Śr. 15/02 " [4]=> string(68) " Cz. 16/02 " [5]=> string(68) " Pt. 17/02 " [6]=> string(68) " So. 18/02 " [7]=> string(67) " N. 19/02 " } [1]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(40) " TGEgasDA " } [2]=> array(8) { [0]=> string(8) "PLN/MWh " [1]=> string(44) " 92.56 " [2]=> string(44) " 91.36 " [3]=> string(44) " 89.51 " [4]=> string(44) " 87.62 " [5]=> string(44) " 88.01 " [6]=> string(44) " 84.63 " [7]=> string(44) " 84.90 " } [3]=> array(8) { [0]=> string(4) "MWh " [1]=> string(54) " 155 808.00 " [2]=> string(54) " 131 256.00 " [3]=> string(54) " 106 008.00 " [4]=> string(53) " 60 600.00 " [5]=> string(53) " 41 520.00 " [6]=> string(52) " 5 880.00 " [7]=> string(52) " 6 744.00 " } [4]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(40) " TGEsgtDA " } [5]=> array(8) { [0]=> string(8) "PLN/MWh " [1]=> string(40) " - " [2]=> string(40) " - " [3]=> string(40) " - " [4]=> string(40) " - " [5]=> string(40) " - " [6]=> string(40) " - " [7]=> string(40) " - " } [6]=> array(8) { [0]=> string(4) "MWh " [1]=> string(40) " - " [2]=> string(40) " - " [3]=> string(40) " - " [4]=> string(40) " - " [5]=> string(40) " - " [6]=> string(40) " - " [7]=> string(40) " - " } } array(7) { [0]=> string(54) " 155 808.00 " [1]=> string(54) " 131 256.00 " [2]=> string(54) " 106 008.00 " [3]=> string(53) " 60 600.00 " [4]=> string(53) " 41 520.00 " [5]=> string(52) " 5 880.00 " [6]=> string(52) " 6 744.00 " }
```

And `json_encode($rowData);`

```
[["RDNpg"," \t Pn. \t 13\/02 \t "," \t Wt. \t 14\/02 \t "," \t \u015ar. \t 15\/02 \t "," \t Cz. \t 16\/02 \t "," \t Pt. \t 17\/02 \t "," \t So. \t 18\/02 \t "," \t N. \t 19\/02 \t "],[" \t TGEgasDA \t "],["PLN\/MWh "," \t 92.56 \t "," \t 91.36 \t "," \t 89.51 \t "," \t 87.62 \t "," \t 88.01 \t "," \t 84.63 \t "," \t 84.90 \t "],["MWh "," \t 155 808.00 \t "," \t 131 256.00 \t "," \t 106 008.00 \t "," \t 60 600.00 \t "," \t 41 520.00 \t "," \t 5 880.00 \t "," \t 6 744.00 \t "],[" \t TGEsgtDA \t "],["PLN\/MWh "," \t - \t "," \t - \t "," \t - \t "," \t - \t "," \t - \t "," \t - \t "," \t - \t "],["MWh "," \t - \t "," \t - \t "," \t - \t "," \t - \t "," \t - \t "," \t - \t "," \t - \t "]]
```

**EDIT 2** I used `bin2hex()` to see what is realy inside `$a2` array. I got:

```
20200920202020202020202020202020202020313535266e6273703b3830382e30302020200920202020202020202020202020202020
20200920202020202020202020202020202020313331266e6273703b3235362e30302020200920202020202020202020202020202020
20200920202020202020202020202020202020313036266e6273703b3030382e30302020200920202020202020202020202020202020
202009202020202020202020202020202020203630266e6273703b3630302e30302020200920202020202020202020202020202020
202009202020202020202020202020202020203431266e6273703b3532302e30302020200920202020202020202020202020202020
2020092020202020202020202020202020202035266e6273703b3838302e30302020200920202020202020202020202020202020
2020092020202020202020202020202020202036266e6273703b3734342e30302020200920202020202020202020202020202020
```

Am I right that mysterious space is no-break space `&nbsp;` and that is why trim function with normal space doesn't work?

Comment: Maybe you need to be using a multi byte function as `string(54) " 155 808.00 " ` definitely does not compute for a single byte character set

Comment: Possible duplicate of [search and replace value in PHP array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8668826/search-and-replace-value-in-php-array)

Comment: you should sanitize/prepare values of the initial array `$subject` beforehand.

Comment: `[0]=> string(5) "RDNpg"` this makes sense. `string(68) " Pn. 13/02 "` **this does not make sense unless its a multi byte character set**

Comment: @RiggsFolly I scrapped data from web and put it into my array. What does it mean that it is a multi byte character set? Should I somehow change it ?

Comment: Or maybe the spaces are not spaces but some odd invisible bytes

Comment: @RiggsFolly is there a way to see what is realy in these spaces?

Comment: Well `\t` is a tab character, but that does no explain the extra invisible bytes

Comment: @RiggsFolly maybe it is some kind of formating - what else can seperates thousands from hundreds?

Comment: All I can suggest is to use a decent editor that lets you look at the strings as HEX

Comment: @RiggsFolly can you recoment some editor ?

Comment: Google "text editor hex free"

Comment: @RiggsFolly I checked and it seems that space was in real no-break space `&nbsp;` I think that it explains why all methods didn't work as should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `array_map`. The code will look like this:

```
$originalArray = json_decode($jsonText, true);

$data = array_map(function($value){
    return str_replace(" ", '', $value);
}, $originalArray);

var_dump($data);
```

**Later Edit**:
Looks like the requirements of the problem got changed and the same the input data.
This changes everything as well.
You can see here http://php.net/array_map how it works, it's simpler and cleaner.

So, having the array with this data (let's take only the first key-value)

```
// this is the actual data from the array
$a = "20200920202020202020202020202020202020313535266e6273703b3830382e30302020200920202020202020202020202020202020";

// make it readable
$b = hex2bin($a);

// see what is inside
var_dump($b);
```

var_dump will return something like:

```
string(54) "                    155&nbsp;808.00                     "
```

So, you have `&nbsp;` which is 6 characters written and displayed only one.

What solution I see in this case would be to use `trim` function to remove the spaces from the beginning and the end of the string, and then to use `preg_replace` to remove all non digit characters and dots.

```
$b = trim($b);
$b = preg_replace("/([^0-9\.]+)/", '', $b);
```

The result will be then:

```
string(9) "155808.00"
```

So, the end result will look like this:

```
$data = array_map(function($value){
    $value = trim($value);

    return preg_replace("/([^0-9\.]+)/", '', $value);
}, $originalArray);
```

Comment: Nobody is listening. See `[1]=> string(68) " Pn. 13/02 "` that string is not 68 characters long

Answer (score 2):

Try this out:

```
<?php

$rowData = array(
    array(
        "RDNpg",
        " Pn. 13/02 ",
        " Wt. 14/02 ",
        " Śr. 15/02 ",
        " Cz. 16/02 ",
        " Pt. 17/02 ",
        " So. 18/02 ",
        " N. 19/02 ",
    ),
    array(" TGEgasDA "),
    array(
        "PLN/MWh ",
        " 92.56 ",
        " 91.36 ",
        " 89.51 ",
        " 87.62 ",
        " 88.01 ",
        " 84.63 ",
        " 84.90 "),
    array(
        "MWh ",
        " 155 808.00 ",
        " 131 256.00 ",
        " 106 008.00 ",
        " 60 600.00 ",
        " 41 520.00 ",
        " 5 880.00 ",
        " 6 744.00 "
    ),
    array(
        " TGEsgtDA ",
    ),
    array(
        "PLN/MWh ",
        " - ",
        " - ",
        " - ",
        " - ",
        " - ",
        " - ",
        " - "
    ),
    array(
        "MWh ",
        " - ",
        " - ",
        " - ",
        " - ",
        " - ",
        " - ",
        " - "
    )
);

$a2 = array($rowData[3][1], $rowData[3][2], $rowData[3][3], $rowData[3][4], $rowData[3][5], $rowData[3][6], $rowData[3][7]);

function trimmed($item)
{
    return str_replace(" ", "", $item);
}

$a2trim = array_map('trimmed', $a2);
var_dump($a2trim);
```

Here is the output:

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "155808.00"
  [1]=>
  string(9) "131256.00"
  [2]=>
  string(9) "106008.00"
  [3]=>
  string(8) "60600.00"
  [4]=>
  string(8) "41520.00"
  [5]=>
  string(7) "5880.00"
  [6]=>
  string(7) "6744.00"
}
```

That will apply the **trimmed** function to the elements in the array.

Comment: I don't get it, when I define array as you do - number by number it works perfectly. But when I apply it to my array it doesn't - it just trims it. What is happening?

Comment: @piotr how are you creating your array?

Comment: `$a2 =  array( $rowData[3][1], 
              $rowData[3][2], 
              $rowData[3][3], 
              $rowData[3][4], 
              $rowData[3][5], 
              $rowData[3][6], 
              $rowData[3][7]);` var_dump is in my question.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. If you can post your entire file somewhere that would be easy to debug and fix. I took your example with the array and created mine for testing. So if you use your $a2 with the $rowData, do you get the results that I get?

Comment: I have added var_dump of rowdata. I simply don't undestand what might be a reason for different output from same input. When I declare array as you did code works and trims all spaces (include these between). When I declare array as variables from different array - it only trims before and after. According to var_dump both inputs are same so what is happening?

Comment: I dont think the spaces are spaces, they must be some bytes that are not showing. See `[1]=> string(68) " Pn. 13/02 "` that string is not 68 characters long unless there is something non ascii in there **68** bytes

Comment: @srayhunter I think that RiggsFolly it right and that is why it doesn't work as susspect. Is there a way to check what values are realy in those spaces?

Comment: That is probably correct. I would use and editor to view the non-ascii characters. You could echo the characters to a file for output.

Comment: @srayhunter How can I view he non-ascii characters in ma editor?

Comment: You have to have an editor that support hex. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_hex_editors Those are some editors that support hex. I like to use UltraEdit or vim. You just need to find one that you like to use and view the data in hex.

Answer (score 0):

you need to iterate

```
foreach($a2 as $index => $a2str){
    $a2[$index] = str_replace(" ", "", $a2str);
}
```

Comment: I got this output `{ [0]=> string(17) " 155 808.00 " [1]=> string(17) " 131 256.00 " [2]=> string(17) " 106 008.00 " [3]=> string(16) " 60 600.00 " [4]=> string(16) " 41 520.00 " [5]=> string(15) " 5 880.00 " [6]=> &string(15) " 6 744.00 " }`

Comment: @piotr Ohh great :), Please mark my answer if it works for you :)

Comment: I don't now why but it doesn't work - when I declare array number after number to look like my array it works perfectly - but when I declare it as in my question it just trims spaces before and afer. Both inputs looks like var_dump.

Comment: Nobody is listening. See `[1]=> string(68) " Pn. 13/02 "` that string is not 68 characters long

Answer (score -1):

Personally when removing whitespaces I use Preg_replace rather than str_replace

Try this:

`preg_replace('/(\s)/gm', '', $a2);`

Comment: It trims spaces before and after number but not between :(

Comment: @piotr use this instead `preg_replace('/(\s)/gm', '', $a2);` or `preg_replace('/(\s)/g', '', $a2);`

Comment: It gives me this warning: `preg_replace(): Unknown modifier 'g'`

Comment: @piotr `preg_replace('/(\s)/', '', $a2);`? Forgot preg_replace had g implied. My fault.

Comment: Same as for the others. When I declare array number by number it works. When I do this as in my question it doesn't but input (var_dump) look the same :(