# Phpexcel replace null value with empty string

Tags: php, excel, codeigniter, loops, phpexcel

I have noticed that if a cell is empty phpexcel gives it a null value. Is there a way i can replace the null value with any empty string before i loop through  the array and store into the database. Below is my code and i am using the codeigniter framework.

```
public function import(){
        $id = $this->session->userdata('company_id');

          $directoryname = get_company_full_name($id);
            if (!is_dir(FCPATH.'assets/customer_documents/Databases/'.$directoryname)) {
               mkdir(FCPATH.'assets/customer_documents/Databases/'.$directoryname, 0777, TRUE);
              }


        $database_name = $this->input->post('database_name');

        // $data['addressbook'] = $this->csv_model->get_addressbook($id);
        $data['errors'] = '';    //initialize  upload error array to empty

        $config['upload_path'] = FCPATH.'assets/customer_documents/Databases/'.$directoryname;
        $config['allowed_types'] = '*';
        $config['max_size'] = '';

        $this->upload->initialize($config);

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload()) {
            $data['errors'] = $this->upload->display_errors();

            $data['databases'] = $this->database->get_databases($id);

            $this->session->set_flashdata($data);
            redirect(base_url().'Databases');
        } else {
          $file_data = $this->upload->data();

          $file_ext = $file_data['file_ext'];

          // use custom function to determine if filetype is allowed
          if (allow_csv_type($file_ext))
          {

            $file_path =  FCPATH.'assets/customer_documents/Databases/'.$directoryname. '/' .$file_data['file_name'];


          //read file from path
          $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($file_path);



          $date_uploaded = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

            if ($objPHPExcel) {
                  //get only the Cell Collection
                  $cell_collection = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCellCollection();


                  //extract to a PHP readable array format
                foreach ($cell_collection as $cell) {
                    $column = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($cell)->getColumn();
                    $row = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($cell)->getRow();
                    $data_value = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($cell)->getValue();
                    //header will/should be in row 1 only. of course this can be modified to suit your need.
                    if ($row == 1) {
                        $header[$row][$column] = $data_value;
                    } else {
                        $arr_data[$row][$column] = $data_value;
                    }
                }

                // array_shift($arr_data); // removes the 1st/header element

                //store the database name and details
                $database_data  = array(
                  'db_name'=>$database_name,
                  'company_id' => $id,
                  'deleted' => 0,
                  'date_uploaded'=> $date_uploaded
                );

                $this->database->insert_db($database_data);

                $database_id = $this->db->insert_id();


                foreach ($arr_data as $row) {

                      $insert_data = array(
                          'company_id' => $this->session->userdata('company_id'),
                          'number'=>$row['A'],
                          'province'=>$row['B'],
                          'district'=>$row['C'],
                          'ward'=>$row['D'],
                          'farming_type'=>$row['E'],
                          'commodity'=>$row['F'],
                          'database_name'=>$database_name,
                          'db_id' =>$database_id,
                          'deleted' => 0,
                          'date_uploaded'=>$date_uploaded
                      );
                    $this->database->insert_csv($insert_data, $id);
                  }

                 log_message('info', '*****************************Customer with the ID: '.$this->session->userdata('company_id').' and name: '.get_company_full_name($this->session->userdata('company_id')).' uploaded a csv database. The uploder phone number: '.$this->session->userdata('phone').' The database ID: '.$database_id.' The database name: '.$database_name.'*****************************');


                 $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Data Imported Succesfully');
                 redirect(base_url().'Databases');

        } else{
            $data['errors'] = "Error occured";
            $data['page_class'] = 'Databases-page';
            $data['title'] = 'Databases';
            $data['content_view'] = 'Databases/index';
            $this->template->admin_template($data);
          }
          }
           else {

              $this->session->set_flashdata('errors','File type is not allowed!');
               redirect('Databases');
            }

    }

  }

}
```

I am just looking for a way i can add empty sting values on the empty cells that are coming with null values.

Comment: Try changing line to `$data_value = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($cell)->getValue() ?: '';`

Comment: Thanks but it is still giving me null values

Comment: Try `??` operator if PHP7 is used.

Comment: sorry. i dont understand. how and where do i do this?

Comment: `$data_value = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($cell)->getValue() ?? '';`

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 1):

Just use a simple array modifier before it reaches PHPExcel.

If performance is an issue, one may consider not to create multiple functions within array_map(). Note that isset() is extremely fast, and this solutions does not call any other functions at all.

```
$replacements = array(
    'search1' => 'replace1',
    'search2' => 'replace2',
    'search3' => 'replace3'
);
foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
    if (isset($replacements[$value])) {
        $a[$key] = $replacements[$value];
    }
}
```

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32321702/4272537