# I have Image Column in my database and it accepts an array values so is there any way can i update the images individually

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, error-handling, eloquent

i have a project to make a dynamic website using laravel where the admin can update all parts via admin panel the client has Projects part and it has multi images i did insert the images to database as an array [this screenshot of the database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4nbJ.jpg)
i want the user to edit the images individually. i made a function to show each image with button to edit [this image to show individuale images with buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGqTy.jpg)

so once the user click on modify it will get the current image with its unique name until here i can do it but the problem i can not update or replace the image with new image to keep same array just change the selected image

sorry if i am making this difficult but what i want is update one value of array inside my db. anyhelp

Answer (score 0):

If I did understand right, maybe this solution will work

All you need to do is

1. fetch this data
   `$images = YourTableName::where('id',yourDesiredRowID)->get()`
2. assign the images column data to an array

```
   $arr = str_replace(array('[','"','}]'),' ',$arr);
   $arr = explode(',',$arr);
```

3. update this array with the new value
   [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8668826/search-and-replace-value-in-php-array#:%7E:text=To%20replace%20multiple%20occurrences%20of,use%20array_search%20as%20you%20do.)
4. update the query with the new image array after you convert it back to string

```
   $image->update(['images' => $theString])
```

But again if that tha case
Why you don't just create a seberate table for images and assien a relation between it and the users

That will make it alot easier to manipulate

hope that helps!